c++ concepts and template parameters
The following code is fine
std::bitset<24> foo;
static_assert( std::same_as<std::bitset<24>,std::bitset<foo.size( )>> )

Note the use of foo.size( ) which is a constexpr function. So why does the following not work
template <typename T> concept is_std_bitset = requires( T t )
{
    requires std::same_as<T,std::bitset<t.size( )>>;
};

static_assert(  is_std_bitset<std::bitset<24>> ) // This fails

It seem like the t.size( ) is not valid in the concept. Is this a generic limitation of concept definitions and if so is there a good way round it?

Concepts don't run constexpr code, since there's no instance of T t in the first place.

The code that you say is fine might be but in the context shown it is not since foo is not constexpr.  Your second block doesn't work since function parameters are not constexpr

t does not exist; it never exists. It's a hypothetical object that the concepts system uses to decide if the code is valid. The expression t.size() will only check that such code is valid and that the result type of that expression can be used where it is being used. The concepts system will not manifest an object of type T and actually call that function.
Now, if size were a static member, you could call T::size() to get the bitset size. But otherwise, no.
